# Python_ Combining two rows /Filtering rows in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Background:
In the below sheet we are seeing Unique Ids and their Occurrences.People in the list below are having either one occurrence i.e. admit or going through observation first and then they are admitted or vice versa.

I just want to filter those records that are going through the **Observation** first and then they are **admitted** (For eg. cells that are highlighted in yellow).Person was under observation on 10 March and then was admitted on March 12. Eventually I would want to remove those people from the list who went through the Observation to admit process.

Note: This file is just an example with  7 records. The actual file has more than 1000 records.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody has answered yet, I tried myself and here is what I got:
**EDIT:** added functionality asked in the comments (mask3)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'UniqueID' : [160454,160345,160162,160162,150146,150146,123666,124555,155555,155555],
    'FirstName' : "Josh Rolinda Katy Katy Dale Dale Maroldine Sarah Ben Ben".split(),
    'LastName' : "Anderson P D D Taylor Taylor G H M M".split(),
    'Date' : "3/18/2022 3/1/2022 3/10/2022 3/13/2022 3/16/2022 3/22/2022 3/25/2022 3/27/2022 04/01/2022 04/05/2022".split(),
    'Occurrence' : "Admit Admit Observation Admit Admit Observation Admit Observation Observation Admit".split(),
})

#convert column to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)
df = df.sort_values('Date')

#create a mask for ID's which are more than once in the df
mask1 = df.duplicated('UniqueID',keep=False)
print(mask1)
# Output: False False True True True True False False

# create mask which checks in which group the first element eq Observation
mask2 = df.groupby('UniqueID')['Occurrence'].transform('first')=='Observation'
print(mask2)
# Output: False False True True False False False True

# create mask to check time between obervation and admit
days_aloud = 3
#mask3 = (df.groupby('UniqueID')['Date'].diff().dt.days) <= days_aloud
mask3 = (df.groupby('UniqueID')['Date'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().bfill()).dt.days) <= days_aloud
print(mask3)
# Output: False True True False False False False False

filtered_df = df.loc[~( mask1 & mask2 & mask3 ),:]
print(filtered_df)

   UniqueID  FirstName  LastName       Date   Occurrence
0    160345    Rolinda         P 2022-03-01        Admit
3    150146       Dale    Taylor 2022-03-16        Admit
4    160454       Josh  Anderson 2022-03-18        Admit
5    150146       Dale    Taylor 2022-03-22  Observation
6    123666  Maroldine         G 2022-03-25        Admit
7    124555      Sarah         H 2022-03-27  Observation
8    155555        Ben         M 2022-04-01  Observation
9    155555        Ben         M 2022-04-05        Admit
```

I had some problems with the 2nd mask, because first I tried it like this:

```
df.groupby('UniqueID')['Occurrence'].first() == 'Observation'
```

which was the more obvious way to check the first element but it returned a boolean list with only 5 elements (I guess because of the 2 grouped elements) instead of the whole len of df which is 7. If someone knows how to get that done more straightforward, please let me know.

Comment: You output shouldn't have Sarah (124555) since her first occurrence is an Observation

Comment: You only need the second mask: `filtered_df = df.loc[~mask2]`

Comment: @rcshon I only even added Sarah for exactly that case. "Observation" only matters first IF there is a second row with that ID with "Admit". If there is only one entry it stays regardless what the value of the column Occurrence is

Comment: at least that is how I understand it

Comment: you're right. i misinterpreted the question. my bad.

Comment: Hi this helps. I had quick question , in the attached sheet, Person was under observation on 10 March and then was admitted on March 12.ie. her admission difference if I calculate it is 2. How do I remove it based on the admit_difference ? If I want to remove all those records wherein admit_diff is less than or equal to 3 , is there any way I can do that in the same code?

Comment: see my updated answer, i added a `mask3`

Comment: I added a `Ben` to the dataframe and changed the "admit" date of `Katy`. Now you can see, in `Katy's` case the difference is 3 days (2nd row gets deleted), in `Ben's` case the difference is 4 and rows stay untouched. If you want to know the days of difference in the df, just use mask3 without `<= days_aloud` and you get a `pd.Series` with the differences instead of `True/False`

Comment: did it work ? are you happy with the solution ? consider to vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure.I'll try this and let you know if it worked.Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Rabinzel,I tried this but it just removed the record of admit(row 5) whereas I'm expecting to remove that person from the list .Is there any way to remove both observation and admit rows for same patients by using the same logic?

Comment: oh my bad, somehow `mask3` interfers with the original goal (to delete both rows if conditions fit). I will have a look why

Comment: @Anonymous I found a way to solve it. I guess it is a bit dirty, but it works. What happens is that in mask 3 we calculate the difference of the dates but the only the 2nd entry gets the result. Now with bfill the each group gets filled with the result of the difference and the mask is working properly again